# Bootstrap 3 dropdown transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Firstly here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krish7878/pjej7o2m/)

Just a regular bootstrap dropdown, I made a few changes to css so that the dropdown appears on hover (instead of click) but how do I want a very simple fade animation. I tried css transition but it didn't work because the .dropdown-menu element has a 'display: none' applied to it, on hover it changes to 'display: block'. How do I animate an element which changes from 'diplay: none' to 'display: block' or is there any other method to achieve this?

I've already googled this and found out some answer but they didn't help.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.dropdown .dropdown-menu{
opacity: 0;
transition:         all 400ms ease;
-moz-transition:    all 400ms ease;
-webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
-o-transition:      all 400ms ease;
-ms-transition:     all 400ms ease;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Your dropdown appears to be fading in/out correctly on hover already (transition based on opacity change from 0 to 1).  I increased the fade time so it's more apparent.  There are jQuery solutions available as well if you're open to that solution.  http://jsfiddle.net/5zr4r/147/

Comment: @Will: Yes it works, thank you for the demo, but still the problem remains, how do I make sure it appears on my demo?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can override the default style of display:none with display:block, since you're also using opacity:0 to hide the menu.  Give the following CSS a try and see if that accomplishes what you need.  I've updated the transition speed to make the effect more apparent.

```
.dropdown .dropdown-menu{
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;

    -moz-transition:    all 1000ms ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1000ms ease;
    -o-transition:      all 1000ms ease;
    -ms-transition:     all 1000ms ease;
    transition:         all 1000ms ease;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Updated version of your fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/pjej7o2m/1/

Here's a jQuery script that might work as an alternative to hovering over the div (still using the css transition properties for opacity)

```
$(function(){
  var $menu = $('.dropdown-menu');

  $('.dropdown-toggle').hover(
    function() {
      $menu.css('opacity',1);
    },
    function() {
      $menu.css('opacity',0);
    });
})();
```

Updated fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/pjej7o2m/2/

Comment: I did think of this but in my case it's not going to work because there is a slideshow right next to the menu, when I mouse hover near the dropdown it changes to opacity: 1. This is going to work along with z-index. I change the display to block but change the z-index to -1, on hover then change it back to 10. But there must be a better solution. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: It is more like a hack than a solution.

Comment: Yes, the css hover was bound to the parent div which is why the effect occurs when you hover on the side of the button.  I've added a jQuery solution which might work for you too.

Comment: thank you for the js solution, there must be a better way, so many websites have it. I'll have to do a bit more of research.

Answer (score 11):

```
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition:         all 0.2s  ease;
  -moz-transition:    all 0.2s  ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s  ease;
  -o-transition:      all 0.2s  ease;
  -ms-transition:     all 0.2s  ease;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Just add `display:block` and `visibility:hidden;` to `.dropdown .dropdown-menu {`.
Then add `visibility: visible` to `.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {` and you are done.

You need to change visibility since the opacity of the dropdown menu is 0 but it is still there. You can check this by hovering under your button. By changing the visibility your dropdown menu will only be there when your button gets hovered.