# jquery responsive menu not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am  trying to make a responsive navbar using jquery but it seems like the toggleClass is not being applied properly. Below is my js and html:

```
$(document).ready(function () {         
    $(".burguer-nav").on("click", function() {      
        $("header nav ul").toggleClass("open"); 
    }); 
});

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
        <script src="menu.js"> </script>
        <style>
            @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
                a{
                    text-align:center;
                }
                .burguer-nav{
                    display: block;
                    height: 40px;
                    cursor: pointer;
                }
                header nav ul{
                    overflow:hidden;
                    height:0;
                    background-color: #505050;
                }
                header nav ul.open{
                    height:auto;
                }
                header nav ul li{
                    float:none;
                    width:100%;
                    margin:0;
                }
                header nav ul li a{
                    color: #fff;
                    padding: 10px;
                    display:block;
                    margin:0;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #404040;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <body>
     <header>
        <nav>
            <a href="" class="burguer-nav"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i> Primary Menu</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href=""></a>Home</li>
                <li><a href=""></a>About</li>
                <li><a href=""></a>Contact</li>
                <li><a href=""></a>Services</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>  
    </body>
</html>
```

At the  moment,when I click on the link(ancor tag) the menu quickly appears and then disappears again so actually do not even see the menu items.
What can I do to make the toggle work properly? Anything wrong that am doing in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your burger menu is actually a link. When you're clicking it, you're getting redirected to a new page (in this case, reloading). Since you don't want to redirect the user, you can just remove the anchor element entirely. This should work:

```
<header>
        <nav>
            <span class="burguer-nav"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i> Primary Menu</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href=""></a>Home</li>
                <li><a href=""></a>About</li>
                <li><a href=""></a>Contact</li>
                <li><a href=""></a>Services</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

[See JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/n0d7eads/)

Also, if for some reason you'd like to keep the styling provided by the anchor element, you could change `<a href=''>...</a>` to `<a href='#'>...</a>`.

Comment: Thanks it works properly.
How  can I add a better transition to it so that it doesn't drop down suddenly?

Comment: Happy to help @WosleyAlarico. Since I resolved your issue, please upvote & accept my answer, so other's know your problem was fixed.

As for animations, there's plenty of ways to approach this, you could build that animation from scratch or use a jQuery/Boostrap dropdown. Some good resources to start reading are http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25876195/bootstrap-3-dropdown-transition.

Comment: @Decron Bernard. Answered voted an once again thanks for the support.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the page just reloads, because you are clicking on a link. To counter that add a `preventDefault` to your function:

```
$(".burguer-nav").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("header nav ul").toggleClass("open"); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you're not removing the actual `<a>` event, which reloads the page, because there is no data in the `href` attribute.

Either provide a hashtag (`<a href="#">`) or prevent the event by doing:

```
$(document).ready(function () {         
  $(".burguer-nav").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $("header nav ul").toggleClass("open"); 
  }); 
});
```

[More information about](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) `event.preventDefault()`